# iPad and iPod virus?

Tags: ipad, ios, dns, router

Every now and then my iPad or iPod touch will redirect my to a particular site in Safari. Could this be malware of sorts that has crept on to my iMac and then my iOS devices? I don't think it's a popup because it happens at random.

For the record, the site is www.wordslife.com/index.php

EDIT:

This does not happen on iMac, come to think of it. I'm using an open access point in a residential area (I usually use one or two) and my devices are not jailbroken.

Comment: Need more information — Does this happen on other WiFi Access Points? Are your iDevices Jailbroken?

Comment: Does this occur on your iMac as well?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay, I think I've tracked this one down. It isn't a problem with your iPod or iPad, it's a problem with the router itself. Its DNS has been overwritten so that it randomly (about 5% of the time) will redirect you to one of their sites.

Because you're using someone else's open access point, there really isn't anything that you can do about it except to stop using that particular router.

For more info, see these pages:

- [Strange Redirects](http://www.bogley.com/forum/showthread.php?40219-Strange-Redirects)
- [Malwarebytes Forum](http://forums.malwarebytes.org/index.php?act=Print&client=printer&f=7&t=59323)
- [Random Browser Redirects, TDSS?](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/lofiversion/index.php/t341635.html)
- or [the results of this Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=%2Bwordslife+%28hijack%7Cpoison%7Credirect%29+%28router%7CDNS%29+-site%3amalwaresolution.com+-site%3aspydiagnostic.com+-site%3afreemalwarecheck.com+-site%3afreespycheck.com+-site%3afreeexchangelink.blogspot.com+-site%3ascanforfree.com&filter=0&lr=lang_en)

Answer (score 1):

If it only happens on a particular 'open access point' then the people providing the access point are doing the redirect. 
By the looks of the site they are settting a cookie that they can use for ads and or tracking.